# A proper way to store a converted to string byte array in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc, rsa

Is there any proper way for storing an RSA-encoded String in MySQL without any Unicode problems?

**What exactly I want to do:**
A user authentication with passwords encoded in RSA and comparing the passwords without using a private key. (Both passwords comparing in byte[] or bytearray as String)

Comment: a string != a byte array; they are two different types. BTW: it sounds like the way you are considering to store you password is not safe. Consider using a standard password hash solution.

Comment: It seems to me that if your encoding mechanism is returning an array of bytes then you should be storing the value in a VARBINARY column.

Comment: Once storing in VARBINARY, should I use
preparedStatement.setBytes
and getting it by using
resultSet.getBytes?

Comment: Of course you'd need to use `getBytes`, what else would you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use blob in mysql to store and then campare as it is without decrypting

Comment: Shall I get that blob by using ResultSet#getBytes and then compare with Arrays#equals?

Comment: @KlavyDev - Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @KlavyDev  exctly thats what u need to do.. upvote if u r satisfied with the answer